# How do I resolve "Invalid use of incomplete type" in Wrapper Code?

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I'm trying to write Wrapper code so that I can call C++ routines from C. The C++ routines will be in an EXE file, while the C routines will be in a DLL.  The wrapper code will be in a separate DLL.

I used the code on https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/ as a blueprint, but in that example, all the code ends up in a single EXE.  I've edited my Wrapper code to produce a DLL.

I'm trying to build only the Wrapper code DLL right now.  The Wrapper code DLL consists of three files:  Wrapper.h, Wrapper.cpp, and datatypes.h.  I'm getting "Invalid use of incomplete type" and "forward declaration" errors when I try to compile the wrapper code.  I understand I'm getting the errors because "wr_Class" is declared, but not defined. But where do I add a definition for a class, and how do I word it as a C program?

And why doesn't the code that I'm basing my code on, get those errors? They don't define the type, either. Ever. But their code compiles and runs. I know this because I copied and ran it.  The big difference that I can see is that their code results in one executable, and mine results in one DLL.

I've looked here on Stack Overflow for answers. But the wrapper code examples I've seen here either do not produce wrapper code in its own DLL, and/or they don't define the Class struct either.

Wrapper.h -- I added leading line numbers for reference.

```
 1. // *****************************************************************************
 2. // *                             W r a p p e r . h                             *
 3. // *                                                                           *
 4. // *                        C <----> Wrapper <----> C++                        *
 5. // *                                                                           *
 6. // *  Programmer:   Colleen Kobe                                               *
 7. // *                                                                           *
 8. // *  Project:      Small Business Innovative Research (SBIR) AF051-071,       *
 9. // *                Phase 2                                                    *
10. // *  Date:         July 09, 2018                                              *
11. // *    Revised:    tbd                                                        *
12. // *                                                                           *
13. // *  Description:  This C header file contains the "wrapper" code that allows *
14. // *                data to be passed between the C and C++ code in this       *
15. // *                project.                                                   *
16. // *                                                                           *
17. // *                This code was based on the code on:                        *
18. // *                https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/                     *
19. // *                                                                           *
20. // *  Copyright :    (c) 2018 Infrared Telemetrics, Inc.                       *
21. // *****************************************************************************
22.
23. #ifndef WRAPPER_H
24. #define WRAPPER_H
25.
26. // =============================================================================
27. //                               Compiler Options
28. // =============================================================================
29.
30. // Make sure functions are exported with C linkage under C++ compilers.
31. #ifdef __cplusplus
32. extern "C"
33. {                                       // Export the code below with C linkage.
34. #endif                                  // Close this block below.
35.
36.
37. #define DllExport  __declspec (dllexport)   // Add this code to a DLL.
38. #define DllImport  __declspec (dllimport)
39. #define CALL_TYPE  __stdcall
40.
41.
42. // =============================================================================
43. //                             External Header Files
44. // =============================================================================
45. #include "datatypes.h"                  //  2 a
46.
47. // =============================================================================
48. //                               Global Constants
49. // =============================================================================
50. // tbd
51.
52. // =============================================================================
53. //                                 Global Types
54. // =============================================================================
55. typedef struct  wr_Class_Ignored    wr_Class;   // "C" definition of Wrapper_Class.
56.
57.
58. // =============================================================================
59. //                               Global Variables
60. // =============================================================================
61. // wr_Class*   Local_wr_Ptr;        // Local pointer to Wrapper_Class.
62.
63.
64. // =============================================================================
65. //                                  Prototypes
66. // =============================================================================
67. DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Initialize               (void);         // Perform initialization.
68.
69. DllExport   wr_Class*   CALL_TYPE   wr_Create_New_Wrapper_Class (void);         // Create a "new" wrapper class.
70.
71. DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class     (wr_Class* wr); // "Delete" a wrapper class.
72.
73. DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Terminate                (void);         // Perform termination.
74.
75. // .............................................................................
76. //  Add these in later, one by one
77. // .............................................................................
78.
79. // void     wr_Set_P07_NACK_Counter (wr_Class*  wr,     UInt32 n);   // Set Qty_P07_NACKS_Received.
80. // UInt32   wr_Get_P07_NACK_Counter (wr_Class*  wr);                 // Get Qty_P07_NACKS_Received.
81. // void     wr_mf_Set_P08_SysID     (wr_Class*  wr,     char   SysID_ch [gd_bg_P08_QTY_DATAWORDS]); // Set P08 SysID.
82. // void     wr_mf_Get_P08_SysID     (wr_Class*  wr,     char * SysID_ch [gd_bg_P08_QTY_DATAWORDS]); // Set P08 SysID.
83.
84.
85. #ifdef __cplusplus
86. }               // Export the following code with C linkage.
87. #endif
88.
89. #endif // WRAPPER_H
```

Wrapper.cpp -- again, I added leading line numbers for reference

```
  1. // *****************************************************************************
  2. // *                           W r a p p e r . c p p                           *
  3. // *                                                                           *
  4. // *                        C <----> Wrapper <----> C++                        *
  5. // *                                                                           *
  6. // *  Programmer:   Colleen Kobe                                               *
  7. // *                                                                           *
  8. // *  Project:      Small Business Innovative Research (SBIR) AF051-071,       *
  9. // *                Phase 2                                                    *
 10. // *  Date:         July 09, 2018                                              *
 11. // *    Revised:    tbd                                                        *
 12. // *                                                                           *
 13. // *  Description:  This C header file contains the "wrapper" code that allows *
 14. // *                data to be passed between the C and C++ code in this       *
 15. // *                project.                                                   *
 16. // *                                                                           *
 17. // *                This code was based on the code on:                        *
 18. // *                https://www.teddy.ch/c++_library_in_c/                     *
 19. // *                                                                           *
 20. // *  Copyright :    (c) 2018 Infrared Telemetrics, Inc.                       *
 21. // *****************************************************************************
 22.
 23. // =============================================================================
 24. //                             External Header Files
 25. // =============================================================================
 26. #include "Wrapper.h"                    //  5 w
 27.
 28. // =============================================================================
 29. //                            Set Up Compiler Options
 30. // =============================================================================
 31. extern "C" {
 32.
 33. #define CALL_TYPE __stdcall
 34.
 35.
 36. // =============================================================================
 37. //                        Constants Public in This File
 38. // =============================================================================
 39. // tbd
 40.
 41. // =============================================================================
 42. //                               Global Variables
 43. // =============================================================================
 44. UInt32      Qty_P07_NACKS_Received;
 45. wr_Class*   Local_wr_Ptr;
 46.
 47. // P07_NACK_Pkts   P07_NACKS;           // tbd -- add in later
 48. // P07_Packet      P07_Pkt;             // tbd -- add in later
 49.
 50.
 51. // +===========================================================================+
 52. // |                               wr_Initialize                               |
 53. // |                                                                           |
 54. // |  Description:  Performs the necessary initialization for the Wrapper      |
 55. // |                code.                                                      |
 56. // +===========================================================================+
 57. DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Initialize   (void)
 58. {
 59.     Local_wr_Ptr = wr_Create_New_Wrapper_Class ();  //  Create a new Local_wr_Ptr;
 60. } // wr_Initialize
 61.
 62.
 63. // +===========================================================================+
 64. // |                        wr_Create_New_Wrapper_Class                        |
 65. // |                                                                           |
 66. // |  Description:  Creates a new instance of Wrapper_Class, and returns a     |
 67. // |                pointer to it.                                             |
 68. // +===========================================================================+
 69. DllExport   wr_Class*   CALL_TYPE   wr_Create_New_Wrapper_Class (void)
 70. {
 71.
 72.     wr_Class*   temp_wr_ptr;    // for debugging--shorten this code when it's clear that it works.
 73.     temp_wr_ptr =   new wr_Class;
 74.
 75.     return  (temp_wr_ptr);
 76.
 77. } // wr_Create_New_Wrapper_Class
 78.
 79.
 80. // +===========================================================================+
 81. // |                          wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class                          |
 82. // |                                                                           |
 83. // |  Description:  Deletes an existing instance of Wrapper_Class.             |
 84. // +===========================================================================+
 85. DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class (wr_Class* wr)
 86. {
 87.     delete  wr;
 88. } // wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class
 89.
 90.
 91. // +===========================================================================+
 92. // |                               wr_Terminate                                |
 93. // |                                                                           |
 94. // |  Description:  Performs the necessary termination for the Wrapper code.   |
 95. // |                code.                                                      |
 96. // +===========================================================================+
 97. DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Terminate   (void)
 98. {
 99.     wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class (Local_wr_Ptr);     //  Delete our Local_wr_Ptr.
100. } // wr_Terminate
101.
102.
103. // .............................................................................
104. //  Add these in later, one by one
105. // .............................................................................
106.
107. //     void wr_Class_int_set  (wr_Class* wr, int i)
108. //     {
109. //         wr->int_set  (i);
110. //     }
111.
112. //     int wr_Class_int_get  (wr_Class* wr)
113. //     {
114. //         return wr->int_get  ();
115. //     }
116.
117. //     void    wr_mf_Set_SysID (wr_Class* wr, char SysID_ch [gd_bg_P08_QTY_DATAWORDS])
118. //     {
119. // //        mf_Set_SysID (char SysID_ch [gd_bg_P08_QTY_DATAWORDS]);
120. //         ;
121. //     }
122.
123. }   // extern "C"
```

datatypes.h -- I added leading line numbers for reference. You probably don't need this but here it is anyway.

```
 1. // *****************************************************************************
 2. // *                           d a t a t y p e s . h                           *
 3. // *                                                                           *
 4. // *  Programmer:   Colleen Kobe                                               *
 5. // *                                                                           *
 6. // *  Project:      Small Business Innovative Research (SBIR) AF051-071        *
 7. // *  Date:         March 14, 2016                                             *
 8. // *    Revised:    July 10, 2018                                              *
 9. // *    Revised:    tbd                                                        *
10. // *                                                                           *
11. // *  Description:  This C header file contains public declarations for        *
12. // *                general use data types.                                    *
13. // *                                                                           *
14. // *                I created these type names to establish with absolute      *
15. // *                certainty the range and bit length of an integer variable. *
16. // *                                                                           *
17. // *  Copyright:    (c) 2018 Infrared Telemetrics, Inc.                        *
18. // *****************************************************************************
19.
20. #ifndef DATATYPES_H
21. #define DATATYPES_H
22.
23. // =============================================================================
24. //                            Set Up Compiler Options
25. // =============================================================================
26.
27. /* Make sure functions are exported with C linkage under C++ compilers. */
28. #ifdef __cplusplus
29. extern "C"
30. {               // Export the following code with C linkage.
31. #endif          // Notice that this block is still open. It is closed below.
32.
33. #define DllExport  __declspec (dllexport)
34. #define DllImport  __declspec (dllimport)
35. #define CALL_TYPE __stdcall
36.
37. // =============================================================================
38. //                             External Header Files
39. // =============================================================================
40. #include <stdint.h>                     //  1 c3
41.
42. // =============================================================================
43. //                               Global Constants
44. // =============================================================================
45. // None.
46.
47. // =============================================================================
48. //                                 Global Types
49. // =============================================================================
50.
51.                                                             //  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
52.                                                             //                                       Range
53.                                                             //  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54. typedef signed char     Int08;                              //  -2** 7 .. (2** 7) - 1 [                       -128 ..                        127]
55. typedef short           Int16;                              //  -2**15 .. (2**15) - 1 [                    -32,768 ..                     32,767]
56. typedef int             Int32;  // AKA long                 //  -2**31 .. (2**31) - 1 [             -2,147,483,648 ..              2,147,483,647]
57. typedef int64_t         Int64;  // AKA long long            //  -2**63 .. (2**63) - 1 [ -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 ..  9,223,372,036,854,775,807]
58.
59. typedef unsigned char   UInt08;                             //       0 .. (2** 8) - 1 [                          0 ..                        255]
60. typedef unsigned short  UInt16;                             //       0 .. (2**16) - 1 [                          0 ..                     65,535]
61. typedef unsigned int    UInt32; // AKA DWORD                //       0 .. (2**32) - 1 [                          0 ..              4,294,967,295]
62. typedef uint64_t        UInt64; // AKA unsigned long long   //       0 .. (2**64) - 1 [                          0 .. 18,446,744,073,709,551,615]
63.
64.
65. // =============================================================================
66. //                                  Prototypes
67. // =============================================================================
68. // None.
69.
70. #ifdef __cplusplus
71. }               // export the following code with C linkage.
72. #endif
73.
74. #endif // DATATYPES_H
```

Buildlog.txt

```
 1. C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  "Wrapper_Code.mk"  MakeIntermediateDirs && C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe -e -f  "Wrapper_Code.mk"  all
 2. ----------Building project:[ Wrapper_Code - Debug ]----------
 3. C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall -c  -o ./Debug/Wrapper.cpp.o -I. -IC:\MinGW\include -IC:\wxWidgets\include -I. -I..\Background -I..\Behind_the_Scenes -I..\Main -I..\Resources -I..\Run_Here -I..\Wrapper_Code
 4. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp: In function 'wr_Class* wr_Create_New_Wrapper_Class()':
 5. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp:73:25: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'wr_Class {aka struct wr_Class_Ignored}'
 6.      temp_wr_ptr =   new wr_Class;
 7.                          ^~~~~~~~
 8. In file included from F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp:26:0:
 9. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.h:55:17: note: forward declaration of 'wr_Class {aka struct wr_Class_Ignored}'
10.  typedef struct  wr_Class_Ignored    wr_Class;   // "C" definition of Wrapper_Class.
11.                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
12. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp: In function 'void wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class(wr_Class*)':
13. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp:87:13: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
14.      delete  wr;
15.              ^~
16. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp:85:72: warning: 'wr' has incomplete type
17.  DllExport   void        CALL_TYPE   wr_Delete_Wrapper_Class (wr_Class* wr)
18.                                                                         ^~
19. In file included from F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp:26:0:
20. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.h:55:17: note: forward declaration of 'struct wr_Class_Ignored'
21.  typedef struct  wr_Class_Ignored    wr_Class;   // "C" definition of Wrapper_Class.
22.                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
23. F:/SBIR_Phase_II_A/Wrapper_Code/Wrapper.cpp:87:13: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
24.      delete  wr;
25.              ^~
26. mingw32-make.exe: *** [Debug/Wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
27. Wrapper_Code.mk:101: recipe for target 'Debug/Wrapper.cpp.o' failed
28. ====1 errors, 7 warnings====
```

How do I resolve the "invalid use of incomplete type" warning?  Am I getting it because I'm building a DLL instead of an EXE?  If so, what are my other options regarding how to declare the Wrapper class so that I can deal successfully with both the C and C++ compilers & linkers?

Suggestions?  Comments?

Coding Environment:

```
 Windows 10
 C & C++
 MinGW / gcc / g++
 wxWidgets
 CodeLite v12.0.3
```

Thank you!
Colleen

Comment: You are getting the error because the type *is* incomplete. The *definition* of `wr_Class` is not available where you are trying to `new` it. Also please remove all the boilerplate comments and irrelevant code (relevant read: [mcve]), it makes this a lot harder to read

Comment: The code you reference defines the wrapper struct. Your code doesn't. It's as simple as that; it has nothing to do with DLLs.

Comment: _"Copyright:    (c) 2018 Infrared Telemetrics, Inc."_ raises some eyebrows.

Answer (score 0):

In Wrapper.cpp, no definition of `struct wr_Class_Ignored` exists so you can't access any of its members.

The actual definition of this class probably exists in a separate header, so include that header in Wrapper.cpp.  You'll see that the example code you modeled from does the same.